# Why is the clickable area of my link seem moved away from the actual element content?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created unusual problem which I don't know how to solve or even google.

I've got this popup box on the website I'm working on, and the "close" button do not work. I mean it work but, the hit box area is out of its mind... and place too. You have to click a little above the "close" icon to close the popup. I am using HTML, CSS, and jQuery for animations.

```css
.map-popup {
    min-height: 100px;
    min-width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    direction: ltr;
    background: white;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: 333132;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    bottom: 1%;
    left: 12%;
    opacity: 0;
}

.map-close {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="map-popup" id="map-popup-1">
    <div class="map-title">Jeansy <span class="map-stitle">(Indie)</span></div>
    <a class="map-close"><img src="map/img/xicon.png"></a><br> Produkcja <span class="map-right">24zł</span><br> Transport <span class="map-right">6zł</span><br> Cło <span class="map-right">4zł</span><br> Marża producenta <span class="map-right">5zł</span><br>    Marża sklepu <span class="map-right">54zł</span><br> Podatki <span class="map-right">27zł</span><br>
    <div class="map-btitle">Cena końcowa<span class="map-right">120zł</span></div>
    <a class="map-cta" href="#">Sprawdź</a>
</div>
```

[image: screen of the problem]

[link to the website prototype](http://tymoszczuk.com.pl/web/mapa/map.html)

Comment: And the code is where?

Comment: sorry, just added.

Comment: Please include enough code for a [mcve]. Your current code shows us a blank white screen (as the snippet I activated shows)

Comment: You have a 7 `map-popup` divs all stacked in the same spot, and you're hiding and showing them by using `opacity`, rather than `display: none;`. Opacity will hide items, however it doesn't negate their clickable state/area.  I'd imagine the other items are on top of (and blocking) a portion of the X button. When I deleted all `map-popup` divs *except* for the visible one, the clickable area works fine.

Comment: thank you mister :) You probably right, I will take a look at this.

Comment: Consider modifying the section of your JS that's responsible for the `opacity` change, to also change `z-index`. The visible item should always have a higher `z-index` than the ones that are hidden.

Comment: so... I took advantage of your comments and fix the problem. instead of animating the opacity of elements with jquery "animate" function, I set the css display to "none" for all the popups and use fadeIn / fadeOut functions in jQuery to show/hide them. It works perfect :) thanks for help!

Comment: Not a problem! In general, it's great practice to prioritize CSS transitions over jQuery transitions, however in specific cases (like yours), `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` will take care of the extra work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant fix, but just give the "x" images their own class and apply padding on the top. Something like the following worked for me:

```
<img src="map/img/xicon.png" class="close-icon">
```

With the following css:

```
img.close-icon {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: thanks, if I do not get the "more elegant" solution, I will just use yours.

Comment: The above works just fine as a fix. The "reason" why this visual inconsistency emerged though is just as @Tyler-Roper mentioned, however. That your <a> element (and subsequently your img inside of your a elemtn) is still there even if not visible. It's occupying an opaque row above your img.